# Printing array in sh

Tags: arrays, bash, unix, sh

In bash, if you have an array `arr` and you want to print all its values, the command

`echo ${arr[@]}`

will do the trick. In `sh` however, this command gives a `bad substitution` error. What is an alternative command(s) for this task in sh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a general-purpose array in the [POSIX sh specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xcu_chap02.html). The closest thing you have available for an arbitrary variable is a string separated by some delimiter; usually whitespace separated, but can be separated by other characters if the elements themselves can contain spaces.

`$@` can be treated as an array in POSIX sh, but it's a bit limited due to the fact that there's only one such variable. You can change the value of `$@` with `set`, so you can do the following:

```
$ set -- one "two three" four
$ echo "$#"
3
$ echo "$1"
one
$ echo "$2"
two three
$ echo "$3"
four
$ printf '"%s" "%s" "%s"\n' "$@"
"one" "two three" "four"
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that a string is [the closest thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711786/bash-convert-command-line-arguments-into-array/12711837#12711837)

Comment: Are you sure you can have null characters in a string in `sh`? Even if you can, I doubt that it's a good idea. (The only way I managed to do it in bash is `s=$'foo\0bar`, and I don't think POSIX sh has that feature.) It's common to use `:` as a delimiter (see `$PATH` et al).

Comment: @KeithThompson Hmm, you may be right. `\0` is relatively common to delimit records in a pipe (`find . -name *.c -print0 | xargs -0 grep something`), but you're right, I can't think of any way using standard shell features to get them into a string.

Comment: @kojiro Yeah, I thought of mentioning how `$@` can act like an array in standard `sh`, but thought it would confuse the issue since it's not really a general purpose variable. I'd forgotten about using `set` to manipulate `$@` such that you can actually have a single general purpose array (which is still fairly limited).

Comment: I've used `$'\g'` (the BEL character) as a delimiter to reasonably good effect in some scripts. There's no doubt it's a hack, but it's nevertheless unlikely to occur by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Couple questions:
- Can you provide any further details on the script and how the array is being initialized?
- Are you sure that you're actually using sh? On some system /bin/sh is a symlink something else like bash.

```
ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 2013-06-04 19:52 /bin/sh -> bash
```

I would recommend http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-using-arrays.htm as a starting point.

Comment: Very few systems have an actual shell named `sh` these days. The POSIX shell is simply a specification that any shell can satisfy, so that `/bin/sh` is a link to a concrete shell such as `bash`, `dash`, or `zsh`.