# How to assign Command line arguments to Variables in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to assign the command line parameters to a variable (Entire argument to one variable) in shell script but it is not working 
Here is what I tried:

```
str1 ='$*'
str1 ="$*"
set str1 =$*
set str1 ="$*"
set str1 ='(echo $*)'
set str1 ='$*'
```

Comment: Whats the argument ? And whats the rest of the script?

Comment: A string with spaces

Comment: Put an example in your question.

Comment: Why there is a space between the variable and the assignment operator (`=`)? You need some basics first. Try [this](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sh.html), it talks about some of the basics of the basics.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32290/pass-command-line-arguments-to-bash-script would be a good duplicate but it was migrated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get **one** variable containig **all** arguments; use `$@`:

```
str1="$@"
```

Comment: But note that this breaks the special semantics of `"$@"` - there is no way for an argument to contain a space, for example. In modern shells, use an array instead. This is a massive FAQ.

Comment: Hello Chris, I tried that as well but no luck.
if I remove "set" it says command not found, without "set" I don't get error but nothing is assigned

Comment: do you put this in a script? How do you use this? What output do you get? What do you expect? There are many questions like this around...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711786/bash-convert-command-line-arguments-into-array