# Change values of array that is a copy of argument array

Tags: arrays, bash, sh

I am trying to change the values inside an array that is a copy of arguments array (`"$@"`). Let's say I execute the script as follows: `$ sh script.sh 1 2 3`

This is the script:

```
list="$@"
echo ${list[*]}
list[1]=4
echo ${list[*]}
```

Expected output:

```
1 2 3
1 4 3
```

What I actually get:

```
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
```

Any idea what causes this behavior and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list="$@"` sets `list` to a plain variable, not an array. Use `list=("$@")` to store it as an array instead. BTW, you should generally use `"${list[@]}"` to get the elements of an array, instead of `${list[*]}` to avoid problems with whitespace in elements, wildcards getting expanded to lists of matching files, etc.

In general, this is the proper way to copy an array:

```
copyarray=("${oldarray[@]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711786/bash-convert-command-line-arguments-into-array#12711837) answer. Command line arguments array is not quite a normal array and has to be converted to an actual array first as follows:

```
list=("$@")
```

Comment: Yup, that is it. Just wrap the argument list in `parens`.